# Filepicker.io images taken on mobile safari in portrait mode are sideways

Tags: filepicker.io

When taking a picture using the filepicker.io upload dialog in mobile safari with a portrait angle... the picture gets rendered sideways when completing upload. During upload it is the correct orientation. How to fix?

Answer (score 1):

Use a conversion and add `rotate="exif"` to maintain the rotation encoded in the image's EXIF data.

https://developers.inkfilepicker.com/docs/web/#inkblob-images